# What am I doing wrong? Min(date), group by user

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

```
SELECT min(date(`tx_date`)))) as start_date,
       `account_id` as 'id'
FROM my_table
group by id
```

This is returning each `tx_date` and not grouping and giving me the min for each user. I've tried this for `start_date` as well: `from_days(min(to_days(date(tx_date))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the logic in your query is fine. Does you table `my_table` has an `id` column that is a primary key? The problem might be that the query is grouping by the `id` column of your table rather than `id` alias that you have used in your query.

Try this if its `account_id` you want to GROUP on:

```
SELECT min(date(`tx_date`)) as start_date, `account_id` as 'id'
FROM my_table
group by `account_id`;
```

I think your query has 2 extra closing braces around min(date(`tx_date`)) and should be causing errors.